# Meaning of wrap in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does the meaning of wrap here?

```
// wrap this with jQuery
var $foo = $(foo);
```

Comment: It's hard to understand your question.  Please make your code sample and question more obvious.

Comment: Here's the [related documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). Did you read it ? If so, what's the remaining problem ?

Comment: Depends a lot on what `foo` actually is.

Comment: I think this is an English vocabulary question, not a programming question; "wrap" means the same as "enclose" or "contain within".

Comment: $ is used in jQuery to access one element in DOM. So please specify what is you exact problem.  What you mean by "foo"?

Comment: FWIW, the way I think of it is that wrap code, whether html or javascript, you're fixing it so that you can refer to it with a single name.

Answer (score 3):

`$(foo)` constructs a new jQuery object every time it is called. You can save the value of `$(foo)` into a variable to cache it:

```
var $foo = $(foo);
```

In JavaScript, `$` is also a valid character for a variable name, so you can prefix variables which contain jQuery objects with `$`.

Without seeing the rest of the code, it's hard to say much more.

Answer (score 0):

Foo is being "wrapped" by JQuery, by attributing the return of the $() method to a variable,  you'll be able to use the JQuery specific methods over the foo object. This is a way of "decorate" an object with additional behavior without modifying its prototype.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are taking the element (or selector, or whatever) named 'foo' and passing it to jQuery to create as a jQuery controlled object. This allows you to execute jQuery methods that will manipulate whatever foo is.

For example, if foo is a  element, you cannot do this:

`foo.html('Hello World');` because foo is not a jQuery object.

You can, however, do this:

```
  var $foo = $(foo);
  $foo.html('Hello World');
```

and the innerHTML of the foo element will be set to 'Hello World'.

Comment: very helpful. Is there any difference between var foo and var $foo ?? If answer is no,then why are we using $foo here ?? I got this here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3 .

Comment: This is just a convention that can be used. Since $ is a valid character in a variable, and is commonly used as a proxy for the jQuery object, it can be used to indicate that an element (foo in this case) has been wrapped by jQuery and stored in $foo. No magic, just a mnemonic.